# Copy a group of cells in excel 2010 without copying the formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Is it possible to copy a group of cell results with out pulling the formulas over to a new worksheet ?

what happens now is it copies the formulas with the =Sum(workbook!Formula) to new workbook, I would like only the result [443] not the formula pointing to another workbook - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select and copy what you want. Choose where you want to paste it. RIGHT click, then choose `Values` from the paste options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mark the cells, copy them, go to the place where you want to paste them, right-click, choose Paste-Special => select 'values' and submit.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing the same as above:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> , in sequence (not simultaneous).